# Cannot find any turtle.inspect commands in turtle Lua shell

Tags: methods, lua, minecraft, member

This should be a simple issue but I have been scratching my head for a while - I am using Tekkit 1.2.9g from the Technic launcher and the integrated ComputerCraft turtles. 
I am specifically interested in the turtle.inspectUp/Down commands, but at least from the lua shell within the turtle I cannot find it, trying in the shell gives an exception about calling 'nil'. Does Tekkit remove this functionality or is there something I'm missing?
The turtle I am using is ordinary (not advanced) and equipped with a diamond hoe

Comment: This site doesn't list `inspectUp` as a valid method, so probably it's not available: http://tekkitlite.wikia.com/wiki/Turtle#Commands

Comment: Didn't think to look for the Tekkit wiki, that is a link to Tekkit Lite but it is the same case in Tekkit classic Turtle API, thankyou